# Pseudo CSS element not displaying outside of parent div

Tags: css, element, pseudo-element

I have a pseudo element that is refusing to display outside of it's parent div. I've set it half in, half out so you can see the issue on the following fiddle.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ug88rptL/)

Been trying a whole bunch of different solutions that I've found on here for this but I can't get it working.

Any suggestions?

Code :

```
.box {
display:block;
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
background: #FFF;
width: 350px;
height:140px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #888;
padding:20px;
overflow: auto;
top: 30px;
left:50px;
text-align:center;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #FFF;
}

.box::before {
position:absolute;
font-family:FontAwesome;
content:"\f0d8";
color:red;
z-index: 20;
font-size:80px;
left:50px;
top:-45px;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

- Assuming you didn't need that `overflow:auto;` here is a working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/ug88rptL/1/. I just removed that property.
- If you need `overflow:auto;` and you can use `position:fixed;` on the `::before` pseudo element: https://jsfiddle.net/ug88rptL/2/

### Definitive answer after comments:

- If you need `position:absolute;` and imperatively cannot use `position:fixed;`, just remove `position:relative;` from the `.box` div and use different margins to maintain the original positioning. Works as long as you don't set a `left` or `right` value for the pseudo-element: https://jsfiddle.net/ug88rptL/10/

Comment: This is the problem. I DO need the overflow:auto (the box contains vertically scrolling text), also I need the parent to be set to position:relative (as it gets it's positioning from another element AND .box can't be wrapped in another div. Which pretty much covers all of the other solutions that I've been finding.

Comment: No can't use fixed. Lol, this one is a nightmare I know. As I only need vertical scrolling though can I use overflow-y:scroll?

Comment: No I can see my last suggestion doesn't work. Any other workarounds for this?

Comment: Actually I spoke too soon. I thought you meant fixed on the main div, as it's on the pseudo class I think that works just fine. Many thanks bro ;)

Comment: Actually this doesn't work on my actual code. It's what I was using originally as it goes. When using fixed, the triangle moves when the screen is resized which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Yes exactly. It doesn't do that on the fiddle, but on localhost via firefox it moves in relation to the browser size. This div on the site is nested inside another div which has margin:auto set to center it. This is why it's being such a pain in the ass.

Comment: Well I need to keep the margin auto on the main div, so it depends on what other solutions are possible? Here is an updated Fiddle with the wrap div centered, so you can see the issue in effect - sorry hang on - reloaded the fiddle instead of updating it...

Comment: Thanks bro, but the triangle is still moving independently of the box. I need the triangle to stay locked to the .box div

Comment: If you use a negative `margin-left:;` instead of `left:;` it sticks to your box. Check out the new fiddle on the answer, https://jsfiddle.net/ug88rptL/10/

Answer (score 1):

the ::before pseudo element is treated as a child element of the element you attach it to, so it will always be inside the box. you're better off wrapping the box in another element and then giving *that element* the ::before child

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before).

```css
.box {
  display: block;
  background: #FFF;
  width: 350px;
  height: 140px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #888;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  position: relative;
  top: 130px;
  left: 30px;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper::before {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0d8";
  color: red;
  font-size: 80px;
  left: 50px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I think you are right, there is no way of making this work on a single div is there